# Cloth-like simulation but without creases

Tags: fluid-simulation, cloth-simulation

I'm new to blender and I wonder how difficult it is to achieve the following.

Imagine a scene with small houses and skyscrapers made out of Lego bricks.
Now imagine a very thin and soft scarf that you throw on this.

I saw some great-looking cloth simulations, however I'm looking for something **without creases**.
What I'm looking for is a material simulation that behaves more as if it was a rubbery, sticky liquid (but high viscosity) substance that then dries, so there won't be any creases.

I hope you get the idea. A different way to express the same would be to throw a polyester scarf and then you heat the whole scene to melt the scarf. But without earth gravity so it doesn't run down, but rather with local gravity so the objects pull the sticky liquid towards them.

Is this doable without going super deep?